# How to prove this inequality $x,y\in\Bbb R$, $|x|<1,|y|<1$ show that $\bigg|\frac{x-y}{1-xy}\bigg| < 1$ (and similar ones)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I have to show that the inequality below is true, i tried some thing but got stuck, 
i tried to eliminate the absolute value $-1<\frac{x-y}{1-xy}<1$ and then solve for $x$ and $y$ with no luck...i do not want the answer to this problem but at least a method for solving this kind of exercises.

$$x,y\in\Bbb R\ , |x|<1,|y|<1 \ \ \text{show that} \ \ \bigg|\frac{x-y}{1-xy}\bigg| < 1.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe:

$|x - y|^2 < |1 - xy|^2 \Leftrightarrow (1 - |x|^2)(1 - |y|^2) > 0$

Comment: I do not understand why the last equality proves everything could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Since both numbers $\,x,y\,$ are less than one in absolute value, their squares are less than one, too...

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\frac{x-y}{1-xy}\right|<1\Longleftrightarrow |x-y|<|1-xy|\Longleftrightarrow x^2-2xy+y^2<1-2xy+x^2y^2\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow (x^2-1)(y^2-1)>0$$

and since the last inequality above is trivially true we're done

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that $$x-y\leq1-xy,$$ which is
$$(1-x)(1+y)>0,$$ which is true, and
$$x-y>-(1-xy),$$ which is
$$(1+x)(1-y)>0,$$ which is true again.